# Position transition not working in Edge

Tags: css, css-transitions, microsoft-edge

So i have an animation on an element, which changes background-color, and changes the bottom position from vertical center of parent to bottom.

I just did a test in Edge, and the background is working fine but the bottom transition isnt. It just changes instantly.

I do realize translate would probably work, but i'm interested in knowing wether positioning as in top, right, bottom, left does not work with transitions in Microsoft browsers? It works perfectly fine in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.

My CSS is shown below.

```
.heading-bg{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: calc(50% - 30px);

    -webkit-transition: bottom .5s ease-out, background-color .4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: bottom .5s ease-out, background-color .4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: bottom .5s ease-out, background-color .4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: bottom .5s ease-out, background-color .4s ease-out;
    transition: bottom .5s ease-out, background-color .4s ease-out;
}

.gallery-item:hover .heading-bg{
    bottom: 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);

    -webkit-transition: bottom .6s ease-out, background-color .4s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: bottom .6s ease-out, background-color .4s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: bottom .6s ease-out, background-color .4s ease-out;
    -o-transition: bottom .6s ease-out, background-color .4s ease-out;
    transition: bottom .6s ease-out, background-color .4s ease-out;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="gallery-item">
    <a href="www.example.com">
        <div class="gallery-item-inner">
            <div class="heading-bg">
                <h3>Gallery name</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

.gallery-item has a  fixed height

Comment: could you post HTML as well please?

Comment: Updated. The issue isn't the .heading-bg element not getting its bottom: 0px position. The issue is, that the transition isn't working on Edge or previous IE versions emulated in Edge. So the change in bottom position happens instantly instead of the .6 seconds.

Comment: If you change the  `parent:hover` to an actual class, like `.gallery-item:hover` it will work ... there is no such thing as `parent` in css

Comment: Sorry, parent was an example class from before i added the markup. It doesnt work. Like i said, the css hover effect happens, but it's not animated. The transition never triggers on edge.

Comment: you should use `translate3d` in place of position animations: `translate3d(0, 0, 0)` -> `translate3d(0, -calc(50% - 30px), 0)`. Remove `bottom: 0px:` from the hover state. This does not answer your question, it's just an improvement to your code.

Comment: Thanks @borislemke, as text says i already know translate would fix the issue. I'm just wondering why this doesnt work in Edge, when it's working just fine in most other browsers.

Comment: Ohh sorry, my bad. Should've read more carefully! 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem and managed to figure out what's wrong by comparing both our code.

Here's the part that Edge doesn't like:

```
bottom: calc(50% - 30px);
```

It appears that Edge currently (EdgeHTML v14.14393) doesn't support transitions when used in conjunction with calc().

Comment: I'm going to take your word on that. I changed the entire animation and the project is already live. But i will keep this in mind for future reference. Thanks!.

Comment: It is a bug, and it's still not fixed after more than 4 years https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/105834/

Comment: This is the reason. I had the same issue and fixed it by removing calc().

Answer (score 0):

So I had a sort of similar issue before. It is possible that Edge doesn't support the animation on `background-color` (it didn't for me with `background-image`)

I would suggest to use `@keyframe` this is how i fixed my problem.

Also, you don't need -moz-, -o- and -ms- prefixes for CSS `transition` property. So you can remove those. http://shouldiprefix.com/#transitions .

I will link my issue with the answer, on my question maybe it will help. 
[CSS3 pulse animation not working in IE and FF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40867910/css3-pulse-animation-not-working-in-ie-and-ff)

Comment: Thanks i'll have a read on that later. Background-color seems to be animating fine in my case. Could try it out with keyframes instead.